# SlideShare Does not Load on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, flash, internet-explorer, performance

I have made a simple embed of slideshare on my site. However, on Internet Explorer, it keeps saying "Loading" and nothing appears. However, in Firefox its almost instant. Please **try here using internet explorer**.

Or is it just me? It makes use of Flash and Javascript.

What can the problem be?

Thanks all for any hellp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page works fine in IE9 at least, and the content you say is broken was written in Flash. You might want to watch your HTTP traffic using Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and check for script errors using IE's developer tools (hit F12).

Answer (score 0):

I've check it in Chrome, Firefox, IE6/7/8 and they all seem fine. I haven't checked it in Opera or Safari though.